# Maven error :The artifactId cannot be empty in windows system

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

Can any one help out of this:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.
4:assembly (bin-assembly) on project ingest-scripts: Execution bin-assembly of g
oal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:assembly failed: For arti
fact {rome:null:null:jar}: The artifactId cannot be empty. -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: can you add your pom.xml

Comment: Yeah sure https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_x2i7h_GC-VM0l1aWhncXNLTzQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @KarthikPrasad have you got any idea

Comment: I cannot access the pom.xml due to firewall. Its better to paste it on question

Comment: Can you add the config for the assembly plugin?

Comment: Please add also your assembly descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you forgot the groupID

```
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
   </plugin>
```

That's just a guess! 
Please tell me, if it's working this way...